# C++ Dynamic Dispatch Function

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, dispatch

I'm trying to create an overloaded function that will be called with the dynamic type of an object. I try to do this **without** interfering with the actual class structure underneath, as I don't have direct access (i.e. I cannot add virtual methods, etc.)

As a concrete example, let's think of an AST class structure that looks somewhat like this:

```
class ASTNode {}; // this one is fully abstract; i.e. there's a virtual void method() = 0;

class Assignment : ASTNode {};
class Expression : ASTNode {};

class StringExpr : Expression {};
class MathExpr : Expression {};
```

I want to write a function `act` that will take an instance of `ASTNode` as parameter and, depending on its actual dynamic type do something different.
The call will be something like this

```
std::shared_ptr<ASTNode> parsedAST = get_a_parsed_ASTNode(); // ... received from some parser or library
act(parsedAST);
```

Then, I want to act, depending on the dynamic type of the `ASTNode`.

```
void act(std::shared_ptr<MathExpr> expr)
{
  // Do something with Math expressions, e.g. evaluate their value
};

void act(std::shared_ptr<StringExpr> expr)
{
  // Do something with String  expressions, e.g. write their value to the log
};

void act(std::shared_ptr<Expression> expr)
{
  // do something with other types of expressions (e.g. Boolean expressions)
};
```

Currently though, I cannot call since they dynamic type will be maybe not the ``most concrete type''. Instead, I have to manually create a dispatcher manually as follows, but the method is a bit silly in my opinion, since it does literally nothing else but dispatch.

```
void act(std::shared_ptr<ASTNode> node_ptr)
{
  if(std::shared_ptr<MathExpr> derived_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<MathExpr>(node_ptr))
  {
    act(derived_ptr);
  }
  else if(std::shared_ptr<StringExpr> derived_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<StringExpr>(node_ptr))
  {
    act(derived_ptr);
  }
  else if(std::shared_ptr<Expression> derived_ptr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Expression>(node_ptr))
  {
     // do something with generic expressions. Make sure that this is AFTER the more concrete if casts
  }
  else if( ... )  // more of this
  {
     
  }
  // more else if
  else
  {
     // default action or raise invalid argument exception or so...
  }
};
```

This is especially annoying & error-prone since my class hierarchy has many (> 20) different concrete classes that can be instantiated. Also, I have various `act`-functions, and when I refactor things (e.g. add an `act` for an additional type), I have to make sure to pay attention to the correct order of `if(dynamic_pointer_cast)` within the dispatcher.
Also it's not that stable, since a change in the underlying class hierarchy will require me to change every dispatcher directly, rather than just the specific `act` functions.

Is there a better / smarter solution? Evidently I'd appreciate "native" solutions, but I'm willing to consider libraries too.

Comment: Is it only the base class that is not under your control, or also some of the derived classes? If you have control over all the derived classes, a CRTP approach would be possible. Otherwise you need to have the types and order of the types somewhere in your code. Making a template that generates your dispatch function from a list could be a somewhat more maintainable option.

Comment: unfortunately it's the entire class hierarchy that is out of my control. CRTP seems interesting, but I believe it doesn't fit well, unless I somehow "shadow" the entire class hierarchy by creating a double inheritance structure where every "shadow" class inherits from 1. the original class, 2. it's shadow super. Then I could add my logic to the  shadow classes. However, that still leaves me with an entire shadow class hierarchy that I need to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Never encountered such problem myself, but can think of the following solution.

Create you hierarchy that mimics original hierarchy, has virtual `act`, the base has base pointer, and each cast it to the corresponding derived pointer.

Now, to create the needed wrapper, you don't need properly ordered dynamic_cast, dispach on `typeid` string. So your dispatch is a map from string to wrapper factory.

Sure you need RTTI for `typeid` string, but you would need it for `dynamic_cast` as well.